# How to fetch data from website within the app?

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, web, fetch

I am developing an app for Lawyers to be used here in Brazil and one of the features of this app is to track the phase of the lawsuit as it develops through time.

It works like this: the user fill a form within the app with the info on the lawsuit and it is stored in a database. Whenever the user wants to know if the lawsuit has any new record, he'll push a button and will get the records ordered by date.

The website that the app will fetch is http://www.tjpb.jus.br the problem is that I don´t know how to code in order to get the app access that site, input the lawsuit number and get the reply displayed on an UIWebView.

So could anyone help me, or just give me a guide on where to find a solution for this?

Comment: So, you want to parse some 3rd party site? Do they know about it? :)

Comment: Sergio, that site is a public information site, which I think it´s ok to get data from it. Also there are other windows based programs that does this what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to asynchronously go to server(via that url) and parse data, then show the responses in UIWebView. But as far as i know you will need a PUSH Server and clerify which data you will show from that site.. [This](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) is a great source to get started with app development, you can find video lectures in i-Tunes too

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you really want to do, but one scenario could be that you build a URL, like

http://www.tjpb.jus.br/?...&...

and load it in an `UIWebView` or if there is a webservice there you should use a lib like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to manage your API calls.

Comment: Well, I think that maybe what I want is simpler than what I tryied to explain in my question: the app has a database with main info on the lawsuit, also its number. So all I want is to click a button on the app and it´ll get the number of the lawsuit, go to the site I mentioned fill in the form with that number and get back to the app to the be stored on the database and get displayed like in a table or something.